# Does League of Legends really require all of these ports to be open?

Tags: networking, port-forwarding, gaming

I'm getting started with [League of Legends](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/League_of_Legends) (LoL).  While I'm waiting on the download, the launcher said I should check out their networking troubleshooting page.

Their [network troubleshooting page](https://support.riotgames.com/hc/en-us/articles/201752664-Troubleshooting-Connection-Issues) says to open the following ports:

```
5000 - 5500 UDP (League of Legends Game Client)
8393 - 8400 TCP (Patcher and Maestro)
2099 TCP (PVP.Net)
5223 TCP (PVP.Net)
5222 TCP (PVP.Net)
80 TCP (HTTP Connections)
443 TCP (HTTPS Connections)
8088 UDP and TCP (Spectator Mode)
```

Looking at the list, it just kind of seems numerically excessive, until you get to the bottom and they want you to open 80 and 443.  [Several](http://forums.na.leagueoflegends.com/board/showthread.php?t=831071) forum [posts](http://forums.euw.leagueoflegends.com/board/showthread.php?t=833381) also regurgitate these numbers.  80 and 443 imply that the game is running a web server behind each users firewall O.O  Most ISPs aren't going to let residential customers run servers on port 80 and 443 either.

LoL has servers of its own.  The only reason you should have to open and forward ports is to run your own server, or for something like a game, enable P2P access.

I thought the range of ports was kind of high, but then when I saw they wanted 80 and 443 open, it occurred to me that this list might be a composite of incoming and outgoing connections.  Networking-muggles certainly might not notice or care about incoming and outgoing variations of ports, and which side is using an ephemeral port vs a well known port.

I also found someone on [Sophos](https://community.sophos.com/products/unified-threat-management/f/network-protection-firewall-nat-qos-ips/41362/port-forwarding-league-of-legends) also talking about how excessive these ports are, but in the end I think they just opened them up.

When there is a firewall issue, the application just does not work.  I can't run it yet, but from the descriptions I've seen, the problems they attribute to port forwarding are not actual port forwarding issues.  "Slow connection" is not a port forwarding issue.  "Not working at all" would be a port forwarding issue.

Why do they list an excessive number of required ports?  What ports are actually required for this game?

Comment: You can run http and https on any port, so your analysis, is deeply flawed.  “What ports are actually required for this game?” - The ports the developer listed.

Comment: Why not ask riot games specifically to your question? They most likely list those ports for a reason. If you need the reason - ask the dev? Or you could even narrow it down to: Can I open all other ports except 80 and 443 to get LoL working?

Comment: You are not running your own http/https server you are allowing http/https within the client.  Since it isn’t a browser it’s necessary to forward the port. The content could be for the launcher and/or within the game client itself

Comment: I agree, the likelihood that the game listens on 80 and 443 in normal circumstances is probably wrong.  The assumption that they are correct because they are listed is flawed too.  Your best bet is to forward them in sequence to work out what is needed for your use case.

Comment: @Ramhound If the portforward is for http and https incoming then by definition the PC is an http/https server if it is listening on those ports.  It is very unlikely a launcher would run a service on 80/443.

Comment: Who says they are a service?  I wouldn’t trust the authors analysis of the situation.

Comment: @Ramhound you seem to be unusually aggressive and argumentative today.  Paul and I are referring to the basics of networking, ports, and sockets.  You can read up on ephermal ports on wikipedia https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ephemeral_port, but I suggest a more in depth tutorial to familiarize yourself with networking, ports, and how they play out.  For example, https://www.bleepingcomputer.com/tutorials/tcp-and-udp-ports-explained/ .

Comment: @Darius I guess i probably will have to go to their forum since I've already got a few close requests on this question and a pissed off senior member of the site.  I saw other game questions, so I figured something like this would be on topic and that I would get a better answer here than a forum.

Comment: @YetAnotherRandomUser - First, If I sound argumentative then I apologize, I just don't agree with the conclusions you have made surrounding port 80 and port 443.  Second, I am not being aggressive, you are attempting to read tone when none exists.  If I was upset, I wouldn't have even submitted a comment, there is nothing wrong with your question.  **I just don't agree with your conclusion surrounding port 80 and port 443.**  As civil human beings I think it is important to be able not agree on things, if I had a problem with your question I would have handled in the proper way.

Comment: Of course telling me to "read up" on a subject I am familiar with isn't very kind.  I am also familiar with this particular game and the client it uses and how it displays content (or I was familiar with the client). It is not uncommon for support articles to suggest to port forward 80 and 443 if their non-browser client uses those ports to receive content. **Which is the reason I don't agree, with the conclusion, having those ports requires you to be running a server on them.** Most of those support articles are written for users who have strict firewall settings and/or unknowledgeable users.

Comment: Which I do not believe you to be one of those users by the way

Comment: @Ramhound Is this just a semantics confusion then?  The recipient of a connection is the "server", the initiator is the client.  This is a network protocol distinction.  Port forwarding permits incoming connections, so the recipient is the server, in this case the PC of the OP.  If it is listening on 80 and 443 then it is a server.  It is highly unusual for a software client to be running a server on these ports particularly because of their IANA designation, so the OP is right to question their necessity.

Comment: LoL client isn’t a http/https server.  It act as a server in other regards but it isn’t serving http/https content to anyone.